# Understanding constexpr functions with templates [C++]

Tags: c++, constexpr

I am trying to learn about constexpr functions in C++. I am unable to understand what is the problem with the first function definition. All the variables, as far as I think, should be available at compile time.

I am using Catch2, as the testing library.

sqrtfunc.hpp

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <numeric>

template <class T>
constexpr T max_iterations = std::numeric_limits<T>::max_exponent();

template <class T>
constexpr T epsilon = std::numeric_limits<T>::epsilon();

// This function definition doesn't work
template <class T>
constexpr T sqrtFunc(T x){
    if(x < 0){
        throw std::domain_error("Argument must be >= 0");
    }
    else if(x == 0){
        return x;
    }

    const T c = x;
    T xn = x;
    size_t i = 0;
    while (i < max_iterations<T>){
        T xnplus_1 = xn - (sqr(xn) - c) / ( 2 * xn);
        if (abs(xnplus_1 - xn) <= epsilon<T>){
            break;
        }
        xn = xnplus_1;
        i++;
    }
    return xn;
}

// This function definition works
template <class T>
constexpr T sqrtFunc(T x){
    if(x < 0){
        throw std::domain_error("Argument must be >= 0");
    }
    else if(x == 0){
        return x;
    }

    const T c = x;
    T xn = x;
    // size_t i = 0;
    while (true){
        T xnplus_1 = xn - (sqr(xn) - c) / ( 2 * xn);
        if (abs(xnplus_1 - xn) <= epsilon<T>){
            break;
        }
        xn = xnplus_1;
        // i++;
    }
    return xn;
}
```

test_file.cpp

```
TEST_CASE("SQRT"){
    SECTION("Square root"){
        constexpr double var = 4.0;

        REQUIRE(sqrtFunc(var) == Approx(2.0).margin(0.0001));
    }
}
```

The error I get for the first function declaration is as follows:

```
error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments

 note: see reference to variable template 'const T max_iterations<double>' being compiled
          [
              T=double
          ]
 note: see reference to function template instantiation 'T sqrtFunc<double>(T)' being compiled
          [
              T=double
          ]
```

For the exact same cpp file with the second declaration, I get the correct output.

If it helps I'm using Visual Studio 2017. `C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.16.27045 for x86`

Note: I have made all the necessary imports (`#include`).

Comment: `max_exponent` is not a function, the compiler is complaining about the parentheses

Comment: Why ask a question when the compiler message explain the problem and the documentation even shows examples: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2064?view=msvc-160. Why take 5 minutes write a question when the answer is found in about 5 seconds using Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `std::numeric_limits<T>::max_exponent`, but it's a variable, not a function.